# dim(X) must have a positive length in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

I am following [this article](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-azure-ml/) to run R script in Power BI.

I got the below error when running the code:

> Error in apply(temp, 2, function(x) as.list(x)) : 
>     dim(X) must have a positive length "

part of code:

```
if(nrow(dataset)>0){
  dataset    <- dataset[,c(-1, -14)]
  dataset    <- na.omit(dataset)
  createList <- function(dataset){
    temp <- apply(dataset, 1, function(x) as.vector(paste(x, sep = "")))
    colnames(temp) <- NULL
    temp <- apply(temp, 2, function(x) as.list(x))
    return(temp)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `temp` object is not a matrix, that's why apply can't iterate by column of said object

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same demo and got the same error.
I got a few errors before that around the RODBC, RJSON and RCURL installs, I assume if you got the error above you have succesfully done the library installs.
I have used the code specified in the one drive for Justyna Lucznik as specified in the demo.
I changed all the table names to suit mine.  I found there were a couple of differences in the SQL in the one drive code to the Azure Databse tables I have - specifically at line 6 in the code

> "SELECT * FROM dbo.Titanic where id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.TitanicScored)"

for me once I changed the field "id" to my field name "PassengerId" I got past this error.
So checking your SQL in line 6 agasint your Azure database may help.